# The present vs the past (when it comes to a range of possibilities covering dead and living people and if the answer is someone who has died)

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, present-tense

Suppose there is a list of people who have been named as the candidates for being the best president ever. On the list are the incumbent and some ex-presidents, some of whom have died. How would we ask which one is considered the best? *which of these candidates **IS/WAS (or even both)** the best president ever?*

Comment: You'd say (now, in June 2020) _Barack Obama was a fine president_, so I can't see there being a problem with tense apart from the inclusion of the incumbent. _Which of these candidates is/was the best president ever?_ takes care of this problem.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *well, in my honest opinion, Obama **was** still the best president ever*. So, *was* there is grammatical, right?

Comment: 'Still' there has to be the 'in spite of everything we've considered' sense, but yes. He **_is_**  now a former president, of course. 'Was' refers to his time in office, not his time on Earth.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so, I should include both *is* and *was* here, right?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is the sentence *among all the candidates, obama **was** the best president* grammatical?

Comment: I'd use 'of' rather than 'among', and 'candidates' is perhaps unusual when you're considering an arbitrary historic league-table.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see. So, what is an appropriate word instead of  *candidates* for this context? And what about using *among* for such a superlative degree? Is it wrong enough to be considered wrong?

Comment: @FadliSheikh I don't think you can meaningfully say **was** ***still*** without further context. You could say *at that time in the past, he **was still**,* but if *all* you say is *was still*, the first think you'll be asked is, "When?"